# Convert unicode to "readable" string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, decode, js-xlsx

I'm parsing a CSV text file containing some data (with labels, numbers, symbols, ...) using XLSX.
At some point, my data are parsed and one of the cell content is '\x80', which is the unicode code of the euro symbol.

```
const s = "\x80"
console.log({ s }) // => {s: '\x80'}
console.log(s) // => €
```

When I try to save this variable into my database (Mongodb), it is not recognized as €.

`s.replace("\x80", "€")` is not a solution for me because some other special characters can showed up while importing files.

How can I convert "\x80" to "€" ?

I try some solutions like `unescape( encodeURIComponent( s ) );` but none of them worked.

**Edit**

XLSX is a library to work with Excel files https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs.

Original encoding of the file is `windows-1252`

**Edit 2**

It look like it's a browser problem `\x80` is working on Chrome but not on Safari nor Firfox.

```
console.log(s) // Print empty string on Safari => ""
```

**Edit 3**

I have created this [codebox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-js-excel-csv-to-json-forked-y9cng?file=/src/SheetJs.js) to reproduce

Here is the difference between chrome and safari
[image: codebox demo screenshot]

Comment: What is XLSX and how are you using that to parse CSV files?

Comment: The string contains the euro symbol just fine. The backslash-escaping only shows up when printing not the string itself, but a string literal (like `console.log` does for the object property).

Comment: Is the original encoding Windows-1252? You can use https://github.com/mathiasbynens/windows-1252.

Comment: "*XLSX is a library to work with Excel files*" - why would you use that to parse CSV? Use a CSV parser library.

Comment: My importation module should work with xls file as well

Comment: Please post the content of the CSV file you're trying to parse, the code that does the parsing, and how the output you get is unexpected.